# Como deixar a primeira letra maiúscula?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a função, e funciona perfeitamente:

```
$.fn.capitalize = function() {
function isTRChar(key) {
    var trchar = [231, 246, 252, 287, 305, 351];
    for (var i = 0; i < trchar.length; i++) {
        if (trchar[i] == key) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$.each(this, function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is('textarea') || $this.is('input:text')) {
        $this.on({
            keypress: function(event) {
                var pressedKey = event.charCode == undefined ? event.keyCode : event.charCode;
                var str = String.fromCharCode(pressedKey);
                if (pressedKey == 0) {
                    if (!isTRChar(pressedKey)) return;
                }

                this.value = this.value.replace(/\b[a-z]/gi, function($0) {
                    return $0.toUpperCase();
                });
                this.value = this.value.replace(/@([a-z])[\w\.]*\b/gi, function($0, $1) {
                    return $0.substring(0, 2).toUpperCase() + $0.substring(2).toLowerCase();
                });

                if (!this.createTextRange) {
                    var startpos = this.selectionStart;
                    var endpos = this.selectionEnd;
                    if (!$(this).attr('maxlength') ||
                        this.value.length - (endpos - startpos) < $(this).attr('maxlength')) {
                        this.setSelectionRange(startpos + 1, startpos + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

Mas ela não funciona com **acento**, **cedilha** e em nomes próprios, o **de** ou **do** também ficam maiúsculos.

**Exemplos:** (de como fica quando digitado)

Maria De FáTima

Jose GonçAlves

Como corrigir isso nessa função?

Comment: Não quis copiar o código e jogar aqui, mas esse link tem exatamente o que você precisa (http://jsfiddle.net/q8eDW/5/)

Comment: Obrigado @rLinhares !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá você pode tentar isso [edição]:
Desculpe nem tinha verificado voltei agora.

```js
function contains(str, search){
 if(str.indexOf(search) >= 0){
   return true;
 } else {
   return false;
 }
}
$.fn.capitalize = function(str) {
    $.each(this, function() {
        var split = this.value.split(' ');
        for (var i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {
            var verify = (split[len - 1] == "D" || split[len - 1] == "d") && (str == "e" || str == "E") || (str == "o" || str == "O");
            if (verify == false) {
                if ( contains(split[i], 'de') == false && contains(split[i], 'do') == false) {
      //alert(split[i]);
                    split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].slice(1);
                }
            }
        }
        this.value = split.join(' ');
    });
    return this;
};
$("textarea").keypress(function(e) {
    var str = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    $(this).capitalize(str);
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Primeiramente, muito obrigado amigo! Só não resolveu o problema do De e Do.

Comment: Não consigo adaptar algo para o De ou Do. =/

Comment: Ve se consegue agora pfv.

Comment: Funcionou ok?  | Fiz uma edição.

Comment: Perfeito amigo! Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Nads, rsrs. Posso perguntar qual objetivo você tem de criar esta aplicação? É para estudos mesmo ou outro objetivo? Eu fazia isso quando estudava :D

Comment: Estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro de pacientes da Farmácia Popular da minha farmácia! =)

Comment: Ok, se for em PHP, basta perguntar se tiver duvidas que poderei ajudar :D
Sou bom em PHP.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62940/discussion-between-lucas-p-and-guilherme-lirio).

Comment: Lucas, estou precisando de um HELP no PHP! =)

Answer (score 2):

Expressões regulares também funcionam, e basta apenas uma linha para resolver o problema. As outras duas são só para pegar o valor da caixa de texto e depois para redefinir o seu valor:

```js
$("textarea").keypress(function(e) {
    var str = $(this).val();
    str = str.replace(/(^|\s|$)(?!de|do|d$)(.)/g, (geral, match1, match2) => match1 + match2.toUpperCase());
    $(this).val(str);
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra possível solução é usando `map` para transformar o valor no seu capitalizado e um array de valores inválidos para capitalizar:

```js
const invalidos = ["de", "do"];

$("#capitalizar").on("click", function(){
    let novoTexto = $("#texto")
        .val()
        .split(" ")
        .map(palavra => invalidos.includes(palavra) || palavra.length < 2 ? 
            palavra : 
            palavra.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + palavra.slice(1))
        .join(" ");
 
    $("#texto").val(novoTexto);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="texto">
<input type="submit" value="Capitalizar" id="capitalizar">
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda também @Isac !

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio Sem problema. Boa sorte no resto do desenvolvimento.

Answer (score -2):

```
<textarea value="" onfocus='document.getElementById("id").style.textTransform = "capitalize";'</textarea>
```

> Usando este codigo funciona perfeitamente (chrome e internet explorer).

Comment: Não precisa fazer assim `document.getElementById("id")` basta um `this.style.textTransform`