# Tornar palavras de um array maiúsculas - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,

Com código abaixo, eu torno a primeira letra de qualquer palavra em maiúscula, exceto as palavras que estão no array `wordsToIgnore`e `wordContainAt`.

Agora pensei em atualizar o código e incluir um array chamado `wordUpperCase`, onde as palavras que estiverem neste array, serão completamente maiúsculas.

Exemplo: `let wordUppercase = ['LTDA', 'S.A']`

Tentei utilizar o seguinte if, mas sem sucesso.

```
if (wordUpperCase.indexOf($.trim(word)) != -1) {
    words[i] = words[i].toUpperCase();
}
```

**Abaixo está o código, juntamente com um exemplo**

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $.fn.capitalize = function() {
        // words to ignore
        let wordContainAt = '@',
            wordsToIgnore = ['to', 'and', 'the', 'it', 'or', 'that', 'this', 'dos', 'rua', 'das', 'rh'],
            minLength = 2;

        function getWords(str) {
            if (str == undefined) {
                str = 'abc def';
            } else {
                str = str;
            }
            return str.match(/\S+\s*/g);
        }
        this.each(function() {
            let words = getWords(this.value);
            $.each(words, function(i, word) {
                // only continues if the word is not in the ignore list or contains at '@'
                if (word.indexOf(wordContainAt) != -1) {
                    words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
                } else if (wordsToIgnore.indexOf($.trim(word)) == -1 && $.trim(word).length > minLength) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
                }
            });
            if (this.value != '') {
                this.value = words.join('');
            }
        });
    };

    // field onblur with class .title
    $(document).on('blur', '.lower', function() {
        $(this).capitalize();
    }).capitalize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="lower">
```

Comment: Tem esse post antigo no SOPT falando sobre isso quem sabe não ajuda?
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224603/como-deixar-a-primeira-letra-mai%C3%BAscula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wagner, como seu array wordUpperCase contém somente letras maiúsculas, você precisa efetuar a busca efetuando o toUpperCase:

```
if (wordUpperCase.indexOf($.trim(word).toUpperCase()) != -1) {
    words[i] = words[i].toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Fiz o teste com o código completo, ficou da seguinte forma: https://pastebin.com/CCTWugkZ

Comment: Daniel, não é uma regra, que as palavras do array `wordUpperCase` estejam maiúsculas, não queria ter que me preocupar com isso.

Comment: Se não for usar algum regex, acho que a forma mais simples ainda seria deixar tudo em upper e pesquisar em upper.

Caso contrário, você terá de efetuar a pesquisa via regex dessas palavras, ignorando o case das mesmas.

Answer (score 0):

Simplificando seu problema, você precisa apenas checar se um valor está contido em outro conjunto de valores, correto?

Acredito que o código abaixo, em JavaScript puro, irá atender.

```js
let words = ['foo', 'bar']

words = words.map(word => word.toUpperCase())

console.log(words)

let phrase = 'Lorem ipsum FOO'

phrase.split(' ').forEach(word => {
  console.log(`O conjunto contém a palavra ${word}: ${words.indexOf(word) !== -1}`)
})
```

Resultado do output:

```
[ 'FOO', 'BAR' ]
O conjunto contém a palavra Lorem: false
O conjunto contém a palavra ipsum: false
O conjunto contém a palavra FOO: true
```